# How to show custom error message on Android 2.x with Google Charts?

Tags: google-visualization

It is not possible to display Google Charts on Android 2.x. The following error message is shown:

```
Cannot set property 'overflow' of null
```

Is there any way to show [custom](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#errordisplay) `div` (text) instead of this text?

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) charts will throw "error" events, which you can capture with an event handler:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function (e) {
    document.querySelector('#error_div').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + e.message;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But it will capture and replace any error message. I would like to capture that particular `cannot set property` error and replace its text with something like `android 2.x is not supported`. Can I capture that particular error? Should I match by `e.message` text?

Comment: You don't have to output `e.message` - that was just an example.  You can output whatever you want.